# Rewording/rephrasing english in python

Tags: python

I'm not sure if there is even anything out there to do this. Is there any libraries out there that can reword sentences to any degree of accuracy? It doesnt have to be too intelligent.

Comment: It sounds like it could be used handing in copied assignments without triggering a plagarism detector. What were you planning to use it for?

Comment: Given the user's history of questions, I get the feeling that such isn't actually the intended purpose, as suspicious as it seems off the cuff. :)

Comment: I'm using pyspeech to make a voice response/text2speech control interface for my computer but I want him to have some degree of realism and personality. Rather than responding with "Yes sir, how can I be of assistance?" everytime I'd like that to have some amount of randomness.

Comment: @Mark Byers, my guess is that it is for a MUD, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @justin peel: Thats not a bad idea, could be used for chatting with npc's.

Comment: @mudder: Fair enough. Sounds interesting! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have a solution. But I think you can look at

NLTK Home (Natural Language Toolkit)
http://www.nltk.org/

It has a ready to use Eliza
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.chat.eliza-module.html

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) even comes with a chatbot that pretends to be an teenage girl on IM who likes anime. There is a huge learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **wordnet** package to find synonyms with the same 'sense' for nouns and verbs.

But this will be a lot dumber than you want. You're looking for like, machine translation from casual english to formal english. Tough question and cool. Props to you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this doesn't exist. I'm hoping to start working on something similar later this year.

Answer (score 0):

This has been said, but NLTK would be the place to start. Chapter 8 of the book found on their website goes over analysing sentence structure which will be the first part of writing a program to answer your question. The chapter can be found here: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html . Another good introductory book to learning this tool kit Natural Language Processing with Python.

Basically what you will be doing is parsing a sentence into its words, building back its meaning by grouping words that function together, saving these to variables, and then matching them with sentence templates
 where they may fit. The parser will make data trees (possibly many trees)

[image]